# Does ParameterGrid produce duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

Is it `ParameterGrid` function from scikit-learn 0.22 in Python 3.7.5 that produces duplicates or is it because I don't use it correctly? Have a look at the following example.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
import pandas as pd    
hyper_params_dict = {
        "SQM_FOLDER_SUFFIX": ["_SQM_MM"],
        "HYPER_RATIO_SCORED_POSES": [0.8],
        "HYPER_OUTLIER_MAD_THRESHOLD": [2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        "HYPER_KEEP_MAX_DeltaG_POSES": [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0],
        "HYPER_KEEP_POSE_COLUMN": ["r_i_docking_score"],
        "HYPER_SELECT_BEST_BASEMOLNAME_SCORE_BY": ["Eint"],
        "HYPER_SELECT_BEST_BASEMOLNAME_POSE_BY": ["Eint"],
        "HYPER_SELECT_BEST_STRUCTVAR_POSE_BY": ["complexE"],
        "CROSSVAL_PROTEINS_STRING": ['MARK4', 'ACHE', 'JNK2', 'AR', 'EPHB4', 'PPARG', 'MDM2', 'PARP-1', 'TP', 'TPA',
                                     'SIRT2', 'SARS-HCoV', 'PPARG'],
        "XTEST_PROTEINS_STRING": [""],
        "HYPER_2D_DESCRIPTORS": [""],
        "HYPER_3D_DESCRIPTORS": [""],
        "HYPER_GLIDE_DESCRIPTORS": [""]
    }
    
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in p.items()}) for p in ParameterGrid(hyper_params_dict)], ignore_index=True)
    df.duplicated().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

`ParameterGrid` creates combinations of all values without duplicates.

You have duplicated parameters combinations because `CROSSVAL_PROTEINS_STRING` contains 2 times the value `PPARG`.

Comment: I am such a fool sometimes. :(

Comment: well, it happens :-)

Comment: On a side note, is would be safer to call ParameterGrid using a dict of sets, like this:  hyper_params_dict = {
    "HYPER_OUTLIER_MAD_THRESHOLD": {2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0}, "HYPER_KEEP_MAX_DeltaG_POSES": {1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0} }